# How to use cmake to compile a project written in C and C++ with dpdk

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake, dpdk

I am using `dpdk-stable-19.11.3`, and the NIC is Mellaonx Connect5-X. The project's `main` function is written in `C++`, but all other functions it calls are written in `C`. I use `cmake` to manage my project. I packed all `C` code to a static library. Without `dpdk`, it's fine. After adding `dpdk`, the `CMakeLists.txt` seems missing some libs. It compiled successfully. But when running the executable file, it returns "open file error". Then I added libs `rte_pmd_mlx5` and `ibverbs`. The errors occur when running command `make`.

```
➜  build git:(master) ✗  make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/hewen/demo/build
[ 83%] Built target mylib
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable demo
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dv_open_device':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:830: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_open_device'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_port_query':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:1030: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_query_devx_port'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_qp_query':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:1012: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_qp_query'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_umem_dereg':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:999: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_umem_dereg'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_umem_reg':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:984: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_umem_reg'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_get_async_cmd_comp':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:969: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_get_async_cmd_comp'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_obj_query_async':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:950: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_obj_query_async'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_destroy_cmd_comp':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:937: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_destroy_cmd_comp'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_create_cmd_comp':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:925: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_create_cmd_comp'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_general_cmd':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:910: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_general_cmd'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_obj_modify':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:893: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_obj_modify'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_obj_query':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:876: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_obj_query'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_obj_destroy':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:863: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_obj_destroy'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_devx_obj_create':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:847: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_devx_obj_create'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dv_destroy_flow_matcher':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:815: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_matcher_destroy'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dv_destroy_flow':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:804: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_rule_destroy'

...

/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:517: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_create_wq'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dv_create_cq':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:502: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_create_cq'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_destroy_domain':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:489: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_domain_destroy'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_create_domain':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:476: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_domain_create'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_destroy_flow_tbl':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:463: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_table_destroy'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_create_flow_tbl':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:450: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_table_create'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_create_flow_action_pop_vlan':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:439: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_action_create_pop_vlan'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_create_flow_action_push_vlan':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:426: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_action_create_push_vlan'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_create_flow_action_drop':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:414: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_action_create_drop'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_create_flow_action_dest_port':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:397: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_action_create_dest_ib_port'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_dr_create_flow_action_dest_flow_tbl':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:385: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_action_create_dest_table'
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5.a(mlx5_glue.o): In function `mlx5_glue_destroy_flow_action':
/home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_glue.c:190: undefined reference to `mlx5dv_dr_action_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'demo' failed
make[2]: *** [demo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all' failed
```

Is there any libs I missed? This is my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(myPJ LANGUAGES C CXX)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse4.2")
option(DEBUG "add complie options for gdb" ON)

set(RTE_SDK /home/hewen/dpdk-stable-19.11.3)
set(RTE_TARGET x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc)
include_directories(${RTE_SDK}/${RTE_TARGET}/include)
link_directories(${RTE_SDK}/${RTE_TARGET}/lib)

include_directories(./tools)
link_directories("./tools/")

add_definitions(-pthread)
if(DEBUG)
    add_compile_options(-g -O0)
endif()

add_definitions(-DBUCKET_CLEANER)
add_definitions(-DCOLLECT_STATS -DTABLE_COLLECT_STATS -DLOG_COLLECT_STATS)
add_definitions(-DVERBOSE)

add_library(mylib STATIC a.c b.c c.c d.c)

add_executable(demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE mylib)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE libxxhash.so)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE
        -Wl,--whole-archive    
            rte_ethdev
            rte_eal
            rte_mempool
            rte_pmd_mlx5
            ibverbs
            rte_pmd_e1000
            rte_pmd_i40e
            rte_pmd_ixgbe
            rte_pmd_virtio
            rte_pmd_vmxnet3_uio
            rte_hash
            rte_kvargs
            rte_bus_pci
            rte_pci
            rte_bus_vdev
            rte_mbuf
            rte_ring
            rte_net
            pthread
            dl            
            -Wl,--no-whole-archive
            numa
            rt
            pcap
            m
)
```

Comment: Hi Wen mellanox nic requires libraries and firmware from mellanox to work. Looking at the undefined reference, it seems you have not added the static or shared libraries of mellanox sdk. Plaese add the same.

Comment: I think you are right. But I don't know what I should include. All I can find is including `rte_pmd_mlx5` and `ibverbs `.

Comment: easiest way to figure this out, is to build skeleton or l2fwd and check the make file command inside build folder. Thus identify the missing options.

Comment: Did you mean I wirte a `CMakeLists.txt` to manage the `dpdk` example app `l2fwd`. Then comparing the generated `Makefile` with its original one to see what is missing in my `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: no, that is not what I meant. you can run `make` for mellanox nic for l2fwd. This will generate in build folder `l2fwd.cmd`. Analyze the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS and cross check the missing items.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and other ways, and add some libs. But it seems still missing something. All are in `mlx5_glue.c`, undefined reference to `mlx5dv_*`. I think the `mlx5dv_*` are defined in `libibverbs`. But the errors prove otherwise.

Comment: i am open for live debug

Comment: I sloved this by including `mlx5`. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If using custom Makefile or CMakeLists.txt, one has to ensure the following

1. DPDK is built with appropriate MXL5 PMD
2. For DPDK Makefile is used, libraries added to build path are

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I/path/to/rdma-core/build/include
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/rdma-core/build/lib
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/rdma-core/build/lib/pkgconfig
```

3. Cross check and verify example code like `l2fwd` and `skeleton` works.

note: as mentioned in the comment it is useful to check

- https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/mlx5.html
- check the build flags for example/l2fwde in build folder too.

[EDIT-1] as per the update in comment, the problem is resolved by including `mxl5` library to CMakeLists.txt.